# Should and should_not in rspec 3+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

After updating rspec to `3.3.3` I got a lot of deprecation warnings..

The `should` I change from:

```
    describe "visiting the user index" do
      before {visit users_path}
      scenario{ should have_title('Sign in')}
    end
```

to:

```
    describe "visiting the user index" do
      before {visit users_path}
      scenario{ expect have_title('Sign in')}
    end
```

I hope my refactor is ok.

I got deprecation warning on `shuold_not`, where `expect_not` doesn't work. On the web I keep getting to [this](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1254) page but I can't get to understand the idea in `should_not` resplacment.

Anyway this example deprecated:

```
  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
    scenario{ should_not have_title('Edit user')}
  end
```

And this does get an undefined method error:

```
  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
    scenario{ expect_not have_title('Edit user')}
  end
```

Comment: Try `expect(page).not_to have_title('Edit user')`.

Comment: rspec returns: `Capybara::RSpecMatchers::HaveTitle implements a legacy RSpec matcher
protocol. For the current protocol you should expose the failure messages
via the 'failure_message' and 'failure_message_when_negated' methods.`

Comment: Yes, it is a Capybara issue. You need to update your Capybara version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_expected.not_to`, if you have a subject defined, or the longer version `expect(page).not_to`:

```
describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
  before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user)}
  scenario{ is_expected.not_to have_title('Edit user')}
end
```

Have a look at the [expect VS should section](http://betterspecs.org/#expect) in betterspecs.

Comment: See my comment to @Abraar Arique

Comment: That's actually another question. Looking at capybara issues, it seems to be dealt with at version > 2.3. Which version of capybara do you have? Can you update it?

Comment: So @nir, did it helped?